# How can I have kendo NumericTextBox keep focus during highlighting in a kendo window?

Tags: kendo-ui, focus, z-index, kendonumerictextbox, kendo-window

I have a kendo window that contains a kendo numeric text box:

```
$('input').kendoNumericTextBox({
    decimals: 2,
    spinners: false
});


 $('#win').kendoWindow({
     modal: true,
     width: "969px",
     height: "646px",
     title: "NumericTextBoxTest"
 });

 $('#win').data('kendoWindow').center().open();
```

The jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/e6shF/40/.

In Firefox, you are unable to highlight the numeric text box value. In Chrome, you can highlight the value but can't type over the value while it is highlighted.

It appears to be a focus issue due to improper z-indexing. I'm using kendo version 2012.3.1114 (latest GPL release). This issue is no longer present in kendo version 2012.3.1315 but that version doesn't appear to be available under GPL. How can I resolve this issue using kendo 2012.3.1114?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a .focus() event listener to the input, wrapped in a setTimeout with an input.select() seems to force it to behave normally.

```
$('input').kendoNumericTextBox({
    decimals: 2,
    spinners: false
}).focus(function() {
   var input = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        input.select();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HwrzV/1/

Works for me now in Firefox and Chrome.  Tried to test IE8 but JSFiddle doesn't load. :x

Comment: Thanks. Your answer doesn't provide the normal behavior. The normal behavior (i.e. the behavior in 2012.3.1315 or without the box being within a window) is to have the box get focus on the first and any subsequent click. In your answer, the box gets selection on the first click and then loses focus on the second click. This is the same behavior without your fix. That is, the first click gets focus and the second click loses the focus. However, your answer does provide a way for the user to get selection through one click (or some other action to gain focus)...

Comment: but never allows the user to click without selection. That being said, the would likely work for my users.