# Why does hide column within a grid not work properly in kendo version 2012.3.1315?

Tags: grid, hide, kendo-ui

In kendo 2012.3.1114, I ran across a numeric text box issue (see [How can I have kendo NumericTextBox keep focus during highlighting in a kendo window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656847/how-can-i-have-kendo-numerictextbox-keep-focus-during-highlighting-in-a-kendo-wi)).

I've been unable to find a work around so in the interim I hesitantly decided (because I'm near end of the project release cycle) to try version 2012.3.1315. During my regression testing, I found that issue to be fixed but hideColumn of the grid component to be broken.

Here's a jsfiddle showing the issue

http://jsfiddle.net/e6shF/42/

Here's the code:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
    data: [
        {"foo": {"bar": 10, "moo": "y", "coo": 4}, "too": "test1"},
         {"foo": {"bar": 20,  "moo": "z", "coo": 3}, "too": "test1"}
    ]

},
columns: [
    {
        field: "foo.bar"
    },        
    {
        field: "foo.moo"
    },
    {
        field: "foo.coo"
    },

    {
        field: "too"
    }
]   
}).data("kendoGrid");

grid.hideColumn("foo.moo");
grid.hideColumn("foo.coo");
```

Notice that the second call to hideColumn will hide the column header but not the column data. It appears making a grid.refresh call after the second column hide will remedy the issue but this is was not necessary in the previous version (nor does the documentation indicate the call is necessary). I think this is a bug that was introduced, so I guess I'm trading one issue for a new issue (perhaps many issues).

Any thoughts on

1) how to fix this issue without a grid refresh or

2) why hideColumn is not working in the new version or

3) even better on how to fix the numeric text box issue in the other thread so I don't have to worry about hoping to catch and fix other issues in this new version prior to releasing

would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I noticed that switching the order of column hiding makes the problem go away:

```
grid.hideColumn("foo.coo");
grid.hideColumn("foo.moo");
```

Here's a fiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/rkmqz/

I'll make the dev team aware of this, too.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and letting the dev team know. Unfortunately, in the real application, I can't control the order of removal as there is a UI control that allows the user to hide/show columns.